# R: Combine 2 related cells

Tags: r

I have 2 different data looks like:

(1)

```
name age like
a1   12  game
a2   15  photo
a3   18  art
a4   11  photo
.
.
```

(2)

```
like    color   money
photo   red     10
art     yellow  20
game    green   30 
.
.
.
```

How to combine those data to an .csv file? (by "like" )

```
name age like    color   money
a1   10  game    green   30
a2   15  photo   red     10
a3   18  art     yellow  20
a4   11  photo   red     10
```

Comment: How can `a1` have to different ages? And to solve you problem just use `merge`.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by = "like", all.x = TRUE)` would work if all records of the first data frame needs to be kept - it is assumed that 'like' is unique in both the data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = as.data.table(df1, key="like")
dt2 = as.data.table(df2, key="like")
dt1[dt2]
```